# How can I set a timestamp field with the "update" or "update_all" methods of ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This is a Rails 3 project.

I just can't figure out how to do this. I have two columns:

```
last_migrated timestamp
migration_message text
```

that I would like to update, with condition:

```
:subdomain => "someval"
```

and yet everything I have tried has failed. I have tried about every MyModel.update and MyModel.update_all variation I can think of. The documentation just is not penetrating my thick skull for some reason. Please help.

To clarify, I want to use an AR method to do the following:

```
update brands
set last_migrated = x,
    migration_message = y
where subdomain = 'someval'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the `where` method like this:

```
Brand.where(:subdomain => 'someval').update_all(:last_migrated => Time.now, :migration_message => 'Some message')
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, but if you are trying to update the attributes of the model then use:

```
ModelName.update_attributes!(:migration_message => "The message", :last_migrated => the_timestamp) if ModelName.subdomain == "someval"
```

where the_timestamp is a DateTime object or Date object depending on how you have defined it in the migration.

For update_all usage:

```
ModelName.where(<condition>).update_all(:migration_message => "The message", :last_migrated => Time.now)
```

Comment: edited the answer assuming that subdomain is another attribute of the model. If it is something else then access it someway and add to the if condition similarly.

Comment: I'm looking for an "update_all" type of solution so that I don't have to loop through thousands of records.

Comment: If you want to update all the records with the same message and timestamp try: ModelName.update_all("migration_message = 'The message', last_migrated = the_timestamp")

Comment: Complete documentation here: http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000343

Comment: Thanks, that's the first thing I read. Unfortunately, I'm dealing with updating a Timestamp field here, and you can't use Time.now without some sort of format in a non-symbol update field, eg "last_migrated = '#{Time.now}'" does not work. And the docs have no example for doing an update like: :migrated_at => Time.now when you have multiple columns to update, plus a condition.

Comment: You should try: ModelName.update_all(:migration_message => 'The message, :last_migrated => the_timestamp). Seems mischa has already answered.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("update brands set migration_status = 'COMPLETE', migration_message = '', last_migrated = sysdate() where subdomain = '#{self.subdomain}'")
```

which isn't the best way to do it in AR, and it isn't the Rails Way, but the other things I tried in AR did *not* behave (update_all), so at least this works.

And since no one could answer my question (thanks for trying amit), and this works, then it will remain the answer until someone can offer a better one.